# Traffic Junky API usage in Java and sample code

Tags: java, api

Can anyone tell me about Traffic Junky API.  Can I use it with Java?

http://api.trafficjunky.com/api/doc/

Comment: making clear what is asked / needed

Comment: does my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

A web based API does not depend on a specific language. You can use it in any language.
APIs have endpoints which you can use. Some have JSON, XML and other endpoints.

https://api.trafficjunky.com/api/doc/

There is also a sandbox feature in the documentation.
You can use it to see how the query has to look like.

This gives a hint that the api_key parameter can be used for the API key:
https://api.trafficjunky.com/api/campaigns/stats.json?api_key=123

Maybe you can also define the api_key parameter using the header fields. Just insert your API details and test it using the sandbox.

Making API calls in Java should be easy using the URLConnection class or some library like Apache Commons HttpComponents https://hc.apache.org/ and some JSON library like json-simple, gson and Jackson.

Just some example code without using a library:

```
String api_key = "123";
HttpsURLConnection conn4 = (HttpsURLConnection)(new URL("https://api.trafficjunky.com/api/campaigns/stats.json?api_key="+api_key).openConnection());
conn4.setConnectTimeout(60000); // you may not need this or just a lower value
    conn4.setReadTimeout(60000); // you may not need this or just a lower value
    conn4.connect();
    InputStream in = conn4.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader is3 = new InputStreamReader(in);
    StringBuilder sb2=new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(is3);
    String read2 = br2.readLine();
    while(read2 != null) {
      sb2.append(read2);
      read2 =br2.readLine();
}
String json_string = sb2.toString();
// do something with the result in json_string, better use some JSON library
```